# Understanding DelimeterDecoder in netty

Tags: java, netty, decoder

I just read the [***JavaDoc***](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html) for `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` and I'm concerned about the following question. Suppose I use the following delimeter: `~`. And want to decode messages from clients. As an example of message, lets consider this one:

```
abcdef~jhk~
```

So I expect the decoder produces two messages:

```
abcdef
jhk
```

But what happens if we have some network latency:

```
abc.... long time waiting ....def~jhk~
```

It means it will be decoded in 3 messages:

```
abc
def
jhk
```

Or how? Can someone please clarify this?

What takes care of the receiving the full message according to a protocol in netty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tested by the unit tests of [`delimiterBasedFrameDecoder`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec/src/test/java/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoderTest.java#L49-L67), it confirms that this handler correctly appends multiple frames, even when they arrive fragmented.